# Удалённый рабочий стол в Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, xrdp

Цель - подключиться из под Windows/Linux к удалённому рабочему столу в Ubuntu Linux.

Честно говоря, перепробовал достаточно много вариантов, вот к чему наконец пришёл. [Здесь](http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/Xrdp,_installing) достаточно хорошо описано всё по шагам (на английском).

Практически всё заработало, но у меня возникли две проблемы:

1. Не работает русская клавиатура (с это проблемой народ как-то справляется).
2. Сессия VNC запускается при загрузке сервера и так там и висит. Нехорошо...

Теперь вариант, который мне понравился больше всего.

Сначала устанавливаем xrdp, он есть в репозиториях. Потом нужно установить последнюю версию x11rdp - это нормальный RDP сервер для Linux. Вся проблема лично для меня заключалась в нахождении его исходников. :)

Компилируем x11rdp:

```
# apt-get install subversion gcc libice-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev cvs autoconf libtool libssl-dev libpam0g-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev xfonts-base   
$ svn co svn://server1.xrdp.org/srv/svn/repos/main/x11rdp_xorg71
$ mkdir /usr/local/X11rdp
$ cd x11rdp_xorg71
# sh buildx.sh /usr/local/X11rdp
```

Это займёт некоторое время.
После успешной компиляции стоит сделать ссылки на xserver для xrdp:

```
# ln -s /usr/local/X11rdp/bin/X11rdp /usr/local/bin
# ln -s /usr/share/fonts/X11 /usr/local/X11rdp/lib/X11/fonts
```

И, наконец, указываем настройки для xrdp, чтобы он использовал x11rd. Правим /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini:

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1

[xrdp0]
name=sesman-X11rdp
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

Вот и всё :) На самом деле всё очень просто! Это позволяет устанавливать одновременно несколько подключений, при нормальном rdp клиенте работают все сочетания клавиш и смены раскладок происходят без проблем. Если активных клиентов нет, работает только один процесс - xrdp. Я сейчас сижу на работе через удалённый рабочий стол ;)

Comment: ммм, ссылки непонятные: по первой - "Архив временно отключён", по воторой - "There is currently no text in this page"; может, лучше их убрать, чтобы не смущали...

Comment: Первая ссылка убрана, вторая ссылка исправлена.

Comment: Спасибо. Про вторую не заметил, видать плохо вставил. А первая ещё утром работала. Я подумал, может это какие-то временные проблемы на том сайте и материал скоро вернётся :)

Answer (score 2):

VNC это конечно прикольно, но можно попробовать поставить teamviewer. Он типа бесплатный. Гемора нет. Если нет алергии на wine, то по-видимому лучший выбор. http://www.teamviewer.com/ru/index.aspx

Comment: Беда в том, что для него, как я понял, нужен клиент. Т.е. какие-то действия придётся производить. xrdp+x11rdp, конечно, тоже совершенно бесплатный, но что мне в нём нравится больше всего - что я могу подключиться к своему серверу из любого пк с Windows средствами этого самого Windows. Что очень удобно :)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы, на самом деле, посоветовал поставить NX: очень крутая штука, работает по SSH. С ней очень просто и удобно работать, главное - в правильном порядке поставить пакеты.
Найти можно [тут](http://nomachine.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Если цель - запустить удаленно какое-то приложение X, то можно не воротить отдельный сервер RDP или VNC, а воспользоваться стандартным ssh. Он умеет туннелировать трафик X'ов. Читать [тут](http://my.opera.com/Aminux/blog/ssh) (4-й с конца абзац)

Answer (score 1):

Для "указываем настройки для xrdp, чтобы он использовал x11rd. Правим /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini" нужно выполнить: sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini