# Удаленный доступ linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

На работе поднял ОС ubuntu и на нем 1с лицензионный. У нас имеются 5-6 пользователей, которые будут пользоваться 1с. Подскажите и подробнее опишите какую систему и программы использовать, чтобы эти пользователи заходили одновременно. В windows server 2003 я использовал команду `mstsc`.

Comment: любой доступный vnc клиент?

Comment: @KoVadim, не, vnc вряд ли подойдёт, потому что цепляется к существуюущему сеансу. А тут нужна одновременная работа нескольких пользователей, как я понимаю. Тут скорее всего надо смотреть в сторону пакета xrdp.

Comment: Опубликуйте 1С в Web и пользуйтесь веб-версией.
Если на сервер только база данных живет, то можно цепляться с клиентских мест с помощью самой 1С (у нее как раз есть режимы "толстый клиент", "тонкий клиент")

Answer (score 3):

На Linux сервере VNC позволяет несколько независимых сессий, см. TurboVNC или TigerVNC. xvnc привязан к существующей X-сессии.
На Windows необходим Windows Terminal Server с лицензиями на соотв. количество клиентов.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если в локальной сети, можно по X-протоколу. На локальном компьютере запускается X-сервер.  Делается вход на удалённый с помощью `ssh -Y`. Для медленных каналов данный способ не очень подходит.
2. В linux есть два набора vnc-серверов, одни дублируют доступ к реальным мыши, клавиатуре и видеопамяти: `vino`, `x11vnc`; другие организуют виртуальную видеопамять и устройства ввода в ОЗУ: `vnc4server`, `tightvncserver` и его форк [turbovnc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/turbovnc/), который пока отсутствует в репозитарии ubuntu. Вам просто нужно поставить один из второго набора.
3. [xrdp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/619/130)